# Function executed, but throwing error

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to write the following code: 
**index.js**

```
const http = require('http');
const port = 9090;
const url = require('url');
const handlers = require('./handlers.js');


http.createServer((req, res) => {
    req.path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    let handler = handlers(req.path);
    handler(req, res);
}).listen(port);
```

**handlers.js:**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const homeHandler = require('./handlers/home-handler');
const contentHandler = require('./handlers/content-handler');

module.exports = (path) => {
    switch (path) {
        case '/':
            return homeHandler;
        case '/content':
            return contentHandler;
    }
}
```

**home-handler.js**

```
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            return;
        }

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'content-type': 'text/html'
        });
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
        return;
    });
};
```

When I "Launch program" and run in browser `localhost:9090`, the function handler is executed in browser, but in the debug console it throws:

> TypeError: handler is not a function

Using `console.log(handler)` it shows that `handler` is function, also `instanceof` shows that `handler` is instance of Function. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Could this be due to a separate `/favicon.ico` request? You don't handle that path.

Comment: please show the code of `homeHandler` and `contentHandler `

Answer (score 1):

Your `handlers` function only handle two specific inputs, `/` and `/content`. Any other request will produce an error, since `handlers` will not return a function.

You might say, "That's fine! I'm *not* requesting a path outside of that set of two paths," but I think you might be wrong.

Most browsers will make a request for a favicon by requesting `/favicon.ico` *in addition* to making a request for the actual URL you typed in. If the browser does this additional favicon request, you will see successful results for you intended request (as you do), but then also see a failure message for the additional favicon request, which you haven't set up your code to handle.

I suggest adding a default debug handler:

```
module.exports = (path) => {
    switch (path) {
        case '/':
            return homeHandler;
        case '/content':
            return contentHandler;
        default:
            (req, res) => {
                res.end("Path not handled");
                console.warn("No handler for", req.url);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added module for favicon, but still the same. The module is:

Comment: @RumenStoyanov Have you determined that the issue is actually with the favicon? When you log the paths of requests, what is the path that is causing the error? (i.e., what's the last path you see before the error?)

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs')
const faviconIco = '/favicon.ico'
module.exports = (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile('.' + faviconIco, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message)
            return
        }

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'content-type': 'image/x-icon'
        })
        res.write(data)
        res.end()
    })
}
```

Comment: I added this module for favicon, but the problem remains. Sorry for bad site and code writing, but I'm new in this area and trying to perfect myself.